# Can't see Github branch in Visual Studio

Tags: github, visual-studio-2015

I've been working on my master repository on github for the past week. Aside from a few bugs this has worked fine in Visual Studio 2015. I just created a branch on github. I cannot figure out how to work against this branch in Visual Studio. You can see my branch here:

https://github.com/jsmunroe/SimpleMvc/tree/distmvc

I'm new to git, but I've become fairly comfortable working with it in and outside of visual studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to checkout the new branch in git. Open up git and navigate to your project root directory then run the following commands:

```
git fetch
git checkout distmvc
```

The fetch will make sure you know about the new branch made on GitHub and the checkout will change your working branch. Visual Studio will automatically update to show you the branch you checkout.

Comment: But then what happens when I sync with visual studio?

Comment: The project that appears in your IDE should automatically be that branch. You can check what branch is open by running "git branch" then checking which one is starred.

Comment: That command gives me an error "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Comment: You need to first navigate to your project root directory then run the command.

Comment: Fair enough. I was in my repositories root. But when I run it in my project root, I get "error: pathspec 'distmvc' did not match any file(s) known to git."

Comment: Try running "git fetch" first in case you're not up to date with GitHub

Comment: Sweet. I just tried that. Could you please add that to your answer so others that have this problem can figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not a perfect solution, but if you would be desperate, you can create inside your Visual Studio local branch from origin branch and then you can right click on it and click "push branch" option. That way you will create a branch on GitHub, so you will see your github branch. It's not a good solution, no doubt about it, but in the darkest hours of incoming deadline every bypass is good road, doesn't it?.